# Error en validación de contraseña inicio de sesión

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php5

Tengo un problema con mi logueo ya que si me notifica cuando el correo es incorrecto pero me **acepta cualquier contraseña que se ingresa** y por ende deja entrar al usuario con el correo registrado en la BD con cualquier contraseña no esta haciendo una validación.

Gracias.

Estructura tabla "user"

```
id          Primaria     int(11)
username                 varchar(50)    
name                     varchar(50)
email                    varchar(100)
password                 varchar(60)
```

***código login***

```html
<?php
 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token']!=='') 
 {
   
 //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
 include "../config/config.php";

 $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["email"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $password=sha1(md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["password"],ENT_QUOTES)))));

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE email =\"$email\" OR username=\"$email\" AND password = \"$password\";");

  if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
  {
   

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    header("location: ../dashboard.php");
    

  }
  else
  {
   $invalid=sha1(md5("contrasena y email invalido"));
   header("location: ../index.php?invalid=$invalid");
  }
 }
 else
 {
  header("location: ../");
 }

?>
```

Comment: ENCIERRA ENTRE PARENTESIS (email =\"$email\" OR username=\"$email\")

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta aquí:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE email =\"$email\" OR username=\"$email\" AND password = \"$password\";");
```

Deberia ser así:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email =\"$email\" OR username=\"$email\") AND password = \"$password\";");
```

El OR debe de ir ente parentesis.

[como usar msqli_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770373/how-to-use-mysqli-query-in-php)

Comment: Gracias por responder, modifique la linea que me sugeriste y efectivamente ya no me acepta cualquier contraseña, el problema que ahora surge es que ya no acepta la contraseña actual.

Comment: yo te lo deje en  mi comentario de arriba XD

Comment: Verifica que la contraseña que estas ingresando sea la misma que tienes en la base de datos. Yo suelo utilizar una consulta similar para login y me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @Carlos igualmente te sugiero usar PHP 5, yo no uso php pero la version 5 a la 7, son las mejores arreglan varios errores

Comment: comentarles que la única rama de la versión 5 que recibe soporte en PHP es la versión 5.6, todas las anteriores están obsoletas @simon

Comment: @Alfredo   y la version 7?

Comment: es claro que va en orden ascendente y si la versión 5.6 recibe soporte, etnonces todas las versiones mas recientes también lo reciben con mayor razón